# OpenBSD-based LiveCD/LiveDVD - is it secure? is it offical?

Tags: operating-systems, unix, openbsd

Does the [OpenBSD LiveCD/LiveDVD](http://jggimi.homeip.net/livecd/downloads.html) get deeply audited like the original OpenBSD?

Is it an official "port"?

Experiences with it?

Comment: There is no "offical" OpenBSD Live CD. It's not hard to create your own though from official images and it's even easier to create a live USB thumbdrive image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One security problem with a LiveCD is that its static and there for cannot be updated.  The SQL Slammer worm was memory resident, it doesn't matter if you have a disk drive.  You can install live cd's onto usb drives using LiveUSB Creator.

Check out the new [Debian GNU/kFreeBSD distribution](http://www.debian.org/ports/kfreebsd-i386/).   You have all the power of `apt` and its built on a FreeBSD kernel.

Comment: so it's better to create own livecd: http://www.alti.at/knowhow/obsdlivecd/index.php

Comment: @Lance - maybe. maybe not. If you have the skill and experience to do it I would recommend it as you have precise control over everything that goes on it and you can ensure the latest patches are there, however livecd's such as Backtrack are heavily scrutinised by a wide audience, so it will depend on whether you need that public assessment.